# PyMOL: How to enlarge python's console font?

Tags: python

Is there a way to enlarge python's console font? I'm on Kubuntu 11.04.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Python itself doesn't have a console - but you're probably using it in a graphical terminal emulator program, such as gnome-terminal or xterm. In gnome-terminal, Control+Plus (iirc) gets you a larger font, and in xterm, Shift+NumpadPlus. You can also save your preference, either using the menu or using some [X resources](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/X_resources).

Xterm (and some others) also has popup menus, if you hold Control and a mouse button.

After testing in PyMOL, I find that it uses Tkinter, and has a hardcoded font selection code in `pmg_tk/skins/normal/__init__.py`. In my copy, it selects a Bitstream Vera Sans Mono font, point size from 9 to 12, such that "PyMOL" is at least 31 pixels wide. Altering the limits there is possible, but I'd suggest submitting a feature request to make it configurable.

Comment: Thank You so much. It fixed the console font. The menu font could be fixed using `/usr/share/pyshared/pmg_tk/PMGApp.py` and in there change `pass` after `def initializeTk_unix(self):` line by the `self.root.option_add('*Font', 'Tahoma 14')`. The last font which has to be fixed - is a PyMOL viewer font - it is still tiny.

Answer (score 3):

PyMOL has two windows, a Tcl/Tk Upper Control Panel and a lower OpenGL Viewer.  You can control the Upper Control Panel's font size using `Setting > Output Size > ...`.  You can control the OpenGL Viewer's Object Menu's text size (the A/S/H/L/C buttons) by selecting `Setting > Control Size > ...`.  You cannot currently (easily) edit the Viewer window's console text size.

Answer (score 1):

Here are two files which solve the font problem (works at least for `PyMOL 1.4.1`): [PMGApp.py](https://github.com/bk322/bk-confFiles/blob/master/PyMOL/PMGApp.py)  which should be at:

```
modules/pmg_tk
```

and also [`__init__.py`](https://github.com/bk322/bk-confFiles/blob/master/PyMOL/__init__.py) file from:

```
modules/pmg_tk/skins/normal
```

Screenshoot:

[image]